# Using a having clause with number lookup

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT 
  u.email, 
  sum(completed_on > (now() - interval 7 day)), 
  sum(completed_on > (now() - interval 30 day)),
  count(*)
FROM mturk_flush f JOIN auth_user u ON f.completed_by_id=u.id
WHERE completed_by_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY completed_by_id
HAVING 3 != 0
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Note that the following **does** work:

```
HAVING sum(completed_on > (now() - interval 30 day)) != 0
```

Is there a way to use the alias or index to refer to it instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `Order By` clause, `Having` does not work with column numbers. From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

> ```
> [HAVING where_condition]
> [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
> ```

Now, I would recommend you to never use column numbers, not even with `Order By`. It is error-prone and reduces code clarity and readability for future maintainers.

You can instead define Aliases, and [use them](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) in `Group By`, `Order By`, and `Having` clauses.

```
SELECT 
  u.email, 
  sum(completed_on > (now() - interval 7 day)) AS sum_7day_diff, 
  sum(completed_on > (now() - interval 30 day)) AS sum_30day_diff,
  count(*)
FROM mturk_flush f JOIN auth_user u ON f.completed_by_id=u.id
WHERE completed_by_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY completed_by_id
HAVING sum_30day_diff != 0
ORDER BY sum_30day_diff DESC
```

Comment: thanks, do column numbers not allow you to use them in the having clause?